# How to change image on custom notification button click?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have set up a notification for a custom xml and I can successfully register click events.

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notif_button, pendingIntent);
```

I also have a broadcast receiver that receives the onclick event, no problem there.

As you can see, this event fires *once* when the user *releases*  the button. I need an event that fires every time when the user touches the button, so I can change it. Like every button in android.

Setting selectors in xml did not work. I tried this example:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

It should be possible, since some music players implemented this behaviour. Any ideas to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, this event fires once when the user releases the button.

That's because that's what is considered a "click" -> touch down and then touch up on the same object. If you touch a button, keep it on screen but move out of it and release then the click won't be fired. That's why it works that way.

> I need an event that fires every time when the user touches the button

You cannnot have this. Luckily.

> Setting selectors in xml did not work

Selectors are not for this.

Comment: "You cannot have this. Luckily" - I need something like a simple onTouchListener. It is possible to change button in ontouch event using custom notification though, but I do not know how.

Comment: There're no listeners. All you can have is `PendingIntent`. When it is fired is not up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
private NotificationTarget notificationTarget;

notificationTarget = new NotificationTarget(  
    context,
      R.id.remoteview_notification_icon,
      remoteViews,
      notification,
      NOTIFICATION_ID);

GlideApp  
    .with(context.getApplicationContext())
    .asBitmap()
      .load(eatFoodyImages[3])
      .into(notificationTarget);
```

For further reference please visit
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-loading-images-into-notifications-and-appwidgets

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom notification...define your xmls add your selectors and background and create and trigger your notifications.

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

```
RemoteViews mContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.test_tt);
mContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_action_search);
mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");
mBuilder.setContent(mContentView);

notimgr.notify(1001, mBuilder.build());
```

let me know if any issues.

Best Regds

Comment: My question focuses on the point how you would change (in this case R.id.image) when the user clicks the button. As I have mentioned, xml selector did not work.